# Why the series need to be stationary before using GARCH model on it?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, heteroscedasticity, garch

It is written in online lecture notes that series need to be stationary, and usually the RETURNS series are stationary.
But my lecture notes say that the series needs to have heteroscedasticity in order to apply GARCH on it. So how can it be stationary as well as heteroscedastic? I am so confused!

Comment: Well, it turns out conditional heteroskedasticity of the GARCH type does not imply nonstationarity. The devil is in the detail.

Comment: Hi @RichardHardy, thanks for the reply. I see it would be great if I can have an example using data myself. I just wanted to know if there any statistical test which shows "whether a time-series has conditional heteroskedasticity". Using ADF I can show stationarity. But how to show conditional heteroskedasticity using a test? Is it ARCH-LM test in R for conditional heteroskedasticity?

Comment: Yes, ARCH-LM is one such test.

Comment: Thank you very much @RichardHardy for clearing my doubts.